# Trying to use fetch instead of axios to make a POST request, but the response from the fetch request returns an error, whereas axios doesn't

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a function which uses Axios to send a POST request which goes through successfully and I get the right response. Now I want to try using fetch to do the exact same POST request. Unfortunately, the fetch request returns a `415 Unsupported Media Type` response error and I have no idea why.

Currently:

```
  onBeforeUnload = () => {
    try {
      const defaultPresence = {
        presence: 'AVAILABLE',
        message: '',
      };
      const url = getServerURL() + urls.PRESENCE;

      axios.post(
        url,
        defaultPresence,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}`,
          },
        },
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

The fetch code I've used to replace the Axios POST request.

```
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}`,
    },
    body: defaultPresence,
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` does not recognise plain objects as the body.

If you want to send JSON then you need to encode the data and set the content-type header yourself.

```
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(defaultPresence),
  });
```